# Checking request parameter value in Struts2 tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I have the following code in my jsp:

```
<s:property value="#parameters['test']"/>
<br/><s:property value="'1'.equals(#parameters['test'])"/>
```

now if I access this action like this:
test.action?test=1

I get the following:

```
1
false
```

Wondering, why 1 is not equal to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**:
There is a difference between `""` (double quotes) and `''` (single quotes) in OGNL.

Double quotes evaluate single characters to strings while single quotes evaluate single characters to Character types. You may put *multiple* characters in single quotes and it will be evaluated as a string.

Further request scope is not

```
Map<String, String>
```

but

```
Map<String, String[]>
```

as can be seen below in last 5 lines of the jsp.

**JSP**

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!-- values from action where letters = "abcd" -->
<s:property value="letters"/><br/> <!-- Displays: abcd -->
<s:property value="letters.equals('abcd')"/><br/> <!-- Displays: true -->
<s:property value="'abcd'.compareTo('abcd')"/><br/> <!-- Displays: 0 -->
<s:property value="'abcd'.compareTo('abcd') == 0"/><br/> <!-- Displays: true -->
<s:property value="'abcd'.equals('abcd')"/><br/> <!-- Displays: true -->
<s:property value="'abcd'.equals(letters)"/><br/> <!-- Displays: true -->
<br/>
<!-- RUN with ?test=a&test2=abc appended to the url -->
<!-- Time for the numbers from action where number = 1-->
<s:property value="number"/><br/><!-- Displays: 1 -->
<s:property value="number.toString()"/><br/><!-- Displays: 1 -->
<!-- OGNL strings in certain cases must be double quoted -->
<s:property value='"1".equals(number.toString())'/><br/><!-- Displays: true -->
<!-- As we can see single quotes does automatic type conversion to Character which is then evaluates false-->
<s:property value="'1'.equals(number.toString())"/><br/><!-- Displays: false -->
<!-- here a string is compared to an integer which is false-->
<s:property value='"1".equals(number)'/><br/><!-- Displays: false -->
<br/><!-- Request Variables -->
<s:property value="#parameters['test']"/><br/><!-- Displays: a -->
<!-- a is single quoted so automatic type conversion probably converted it to a Character, which is not equal to string "a" -->
<s:property value="'a'.equals(#parameters['test'])"/><br/><!-- Displays: false -->
<!-- both are strings so equality works as expected -->
<s:property value='#parameters["test"]'/><br/><!-- Displays: a -->
<s:property value='"a".equals(#parameters["test"])'/><br/><!-- Displays: false because #parameters["test"] is a string[] and calling toString on string[] does not work -->
<!-- #parameters['test2'] now is 'abc' automatic type conversion of OGNL swill convert 'abc' to a string and so both are equal -->
<s:property value='#parameters["test2"]'/><br/>
<!-- Double quotes must be a string -->
<s:property value='"abc".compareTo(#parameters["test2"]) == 0'/><br/><!-- Displays: true -->
<!-- Single quote so automatic type conversion... string of chars is converted to String -->
<s:property value="'abc'.compareTo(#parameters['test2']) == 0"/><br/><!-- Displays: true -->
<!-- Out of curiosity I'd like to know if '1' is an Integer or a Byte -->
<s:property value="'1'.toString()"/><br/><!-- Answer: Neither it prints "class java.lang.Character" -->
<!-- 'a' is a Character however equals calls toString() -->
<!-- But the request object (and session too) is not <string, string> but <string, string[]> -->
1: <s:property value='"1".class'/><br/> <!-- class java.lang.String -->
2: <s:property value='#parameters["test"].class'/><br/> <!-- Array of string: class [Ljava.lang.String; -->
3: <s:property value='#parameters["test"][0].class'/><br/> <!-- This is what we need: class java.lang.String -->
<s:property value='#parameters["test"][0].equals("a")'/><br/> <!-- Now this works -->
<s:property value="#parameters['test'][0].equals('a'.toString())"/><br/> <!-- this is another way, leaving off the .toString results in false -->
```

**Test.jsp (Action)**

package struts2;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

```
public class test extends ActionSupport{
    public String letters = "abcd";
    public int number = 1;
}
```

Comment: 1 is just an example. any string behaves the same: <s:property value="'hello' == #parameters['test']"/> doesn't work

Comment: Well no because == is for built in types. Strings can't be compared that way. If #parameters['test'] evaluates to 'hello' <s:property value="'hello'.equals(#parameters['test'])"/> will work.  If #parameters['test'] evaluates to an integer, <s:property value="'1'.equals(#parameters['test'].toString())"/> will work.

Comment: just tested: <s:property value="'hello'.equals(#parameters['test'])"/> produces false on test.action?test=hello

Answer (score 0):

I just found that #parameters['test'] returns an array of String. So when you say

```
<s:property value="'1'.equals(#parameters['test'])"/>
```

you are actually comparing a string '1' with an array {'1'} hence it returns false. Maybe this is because there are two parameters with same name

correct thing to do would be

```
<s:property value="'1'.equals(#parameters['test'][0])"/>
```