# get Request parameter value in <s:text name=""/> Struts2

Tags: parameters, struts2, request

I have a url which ends:

/list.action?t=Local&st=Politics

I want to place the 2 values in 2 `<s:text/>`

I tried to do it this way:

```
<s:text name="%{#parameters['t']}"/>

<s:text name="%{#parameters['st']}"/>
```

But I only get the last parameter value which is "st", but not the first one.

How can I fetch multiple parameter values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same issue as solved here: [Checking request parameter value in Struts2 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560169/checking-request-parameter-value-in-struts2-tag/4560305#4560305)

That being the parameter map is of type

```
Map<String, String[]> and not Map<String, String>
```

and not char[] which the single quotes of 't' evaluates to... long story short these two tags should work:

```
<s:text name='%{#parameters["t"]}'/>
<s:text name="%{#parameters['st']}"/>
```

But note that this works because of OGNL magic and it would be more explicit to write:

```
<s:text name='%{#parameters["t"][0]}'/>
<s:text name="%{#parameters['st'][0]}"/>
```

as this is working closer to the type. Anyways the above linked question should make this very clear.