# struts 2 if tag for comparing character type

Tags: java, if-statement, struts2

I am not able to compare character type by using the below code

```
<s:if test='aCharType == "Y"'>
  This is not working
</s:if>
```

Here is aCharType is of character type of length 1 .

I googled the problem by which i came know that struts 2 if tags works with 
String type.

plz let me know solution if you have it.

Comment: Aleksandrs solution should be good, wrote this answer a while back it would probably be good to review: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4560169/514065 (showing different OGNL expressions and how they evaluate)

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing your `aCharType` with a String `"Y"`, compare it with char `'Y'`

```
<s:if test="aCharType == 'Y'">
  This is working
</s:if>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Syntax is correct.but you should mention the '#' symbol before object.the '#' symbol will mention this is object not a string.if u don't mention it will take as String.

your correct answer is:

```
<s:if test='#aCharType == "Y"'>
      this will work
</s:if>
```

Comment: The `#` character is for accessing named values in the value stack context and has nothing to do with data types.